# splitting string up

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string build up like varstring1_varstring2_id1_id2 eg: move_user_12_2 .

I want to extract id1 and id2 out of the string. Since I'm a complete prototype beginner I'm having some troubles solving this.

Thanks
Stijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably just use the built-in [string.split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) operator

```
var s = "move_user_12_2".split('_');
var id1 = s[2], id2 = s[3];
```

Answer (score 3):

If by prototype you mean the prototype javascript framework, then what you need is the [string.split](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jstring2.htm) method. So, in your case, the code would be something like

```
var myString = 'move_user_12_2';
var stringParts = myString.split('_');
var id1 = stringParts[2];
var id2 = stringParts[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression can also be handy

```
var str = "move_user_12_2";
var ids = str.match(/(\d+)/g);
alert(ids[0] + "\n" + ids[1]);
```